# IBM Worklight - Any live Worklight-based iOS apps?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to find out some **live iPhone/iPad apps** that were created using IBM Worklight. I have Googled around and searched the App Store but was unable to find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is published by IBM is a list of customer [success stories](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/success/cssdb.nsf/softwareL2VW?OpenView&Start=1&Count=10&RestrictToCategory=default_IBMWorklight&cty=en_us).

You can also talk to an IBM sales rep.

Answer (score 0):

May be try [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id514082860?mt=8). Got this info from [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014816333). It may be helpful, but no sure.

Comment: Gone through the 2nd link it but no where mentioned it's been done with IBM Worklight

Comment: Even if Native, it uses in this case the Worklight Native SDK to connect to the Worklight Server; you can do both - hybrid and native.

Comment: @Steve: How can one tell if app was made using Worklight?

Comment: @user523234 I hope you can distinguish a native and a hybrid app. So in hybrid / cross platform app if you are getting direct app update that wd be a signal. Otherwise its tough to differentiate worklight apps from all cross platform apps.

Answer (score 0):

ING Direct, Lotte, Capital One, Air Canada... to name a few; you'll just have to take my word on that.
Whether or not the apps will be available to you, I don't know.

Still, a few (public) sources:

- [source 1](https://www-950.ibm.com/events/wwe/grp/grp037.nsf/vLookupPDFs/Developer%20Days%20Mobile%20Development%20Based%20on%20Standards%20including%20DEMO/%24file/Developer%20Days%20Mobile%20Development%20Based%20on%20Standards%20including%20DEMO.pdf)
- [source 2](http://www.slideshare.net/gaborvodics/worklight-50-webinar-7-12-v2)
- [source 3](https://www-950.ibm.com/events/wwe/grp/grp004.nsf/vLookupPDFs/IBM%20Worklight%20Corp%20Overview%20Neil%20Doherty/%24file/IBM%20Worklight%20Corp%20Overview%20Neil%20Doherty.pdf)

Comment: IBM should showcase all the apps like we see for phonegap i.e http://phonegap.com/app/

Comment: Nothing I can do about that.