# IBM Worklight - How well worklight server suited for large applications

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

For a large application like banking or retail, how well the IBM Worklight server suited? This is, for example based on the number of concurrent requests , security etc?

Answer (score 0):

The are live apps built using Worklight of large-scale companies like banks and airlines, so I assume it works well. [Success Stories](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/success/cssdb.nsf/softwareL2VW?OpenView&Start=1&Count=10&RestrictToCategory=default_IBMWorklight&cty=en_us) ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913637/ibm-worklight-any-live-worklight-based-ios-apps/)).

There is also a [hardware calculator](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#additional-resources).

Answer (score 0):

As Idan mentions, the hardware calculator PDF and Excel will provide you with ample data. One of our production customers has a bank app with 8 digit App downloads and another Chinese customer will add a 9th digit soon. So the answer is -- we are well suited.